# How to make a list of pairs in C?

Tags: c, list

I want to remove the repetition in this code:

```
printf( "%.2f: %s\n",  440.00f, "A4" );
printf( "%.2f: %s\n",  523.25f, "C5" );
printf( "%.2f: %s\n",  880.00f, "A5" );
printf( "%.2f: %s\n", 1046.50f, "C6" );
```

My plan is to make a list of pairs and loop over it. Is it possible and a good solution, or should I just make two arrays?

Comment: You could also make one array of pairs. Depends on how you get your data.

Comment: @Mat: My question is _how_ to make an array of pairs :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just make an array of structs:

```
struct pair {
    double num;
    char str[32];
};

struct pair pairs[10] = {
    {440.00f, "A4"},
    {523.25f, "C5"},
    /* ... */
};

/* C99. */
pairs[2] = (struct pair){880.00f, "A5"}; 
pairs[3] = (struct pair){
    .str = "C6",
    .num = 1046.50f
};

for (i = 0; i < sizeof(pairs) / sizeof(pairs[0]); i++)
    printf("%.2f: %s\n",  pairs[i].num, pairs[i].str);
```

Comment: Alternatively, do `double nums[COUNT] = { ... }; char strs[COUNT][32] = { ... }; for(i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) printf("%.2f: %s\n", nums[i], strs[i]);`

Comment: Thank you! What is the neatest way to initialise the list in the code?