# C: How do I pass a value from child process to parent process via pipes before execv?

Tags: c, terminal, concurrency, pipe, exec

Before I start, I just want to say that this is for a school assignment of mine. I'm really close to finishing, except well, since I'm here, obvious to say, I'm stuck on a problem :(.

First of I'll explain what my assignment wants:
The assignment wants me to create a command-line program in C that allows the user to type in N number of `/bin/` commands (E.g. `> /bin/ps /bin/ls "/bin/which gcc"`). Once the user enters the command and hits the enter key, the parent process (the parent process is the program) will create N child processes (i.e. no. of `/bin/` commands entered = no. of child processes parent process will create). Each child will run one of the N commands. All the children will be running concurrently, with the parent waiting for each child to terminate.
Once a child terminates, the parent will print whether the command executed successfully or not (E.g. `"Command /bin/ps has completed successfully"` or `"Command /bin/ps has not completed successfully"`) and once all children have been terminated, the parent will print `"All done, bye!"`

The issue:
So I've managed to get my child processes to run concurrently, the only issue is that I'm not sure how to pipe the value of the command (like `/bin/ps` or `/bin/which gcc`) from the child process to the parent process to print out the success or not message. I've tried putting the write pipe above my `execv` which allows me to pipe what I want but the execv won't output anything and I can't put my pipe code below my `execv` because in that case, then while my `execv` output will show, my pipe won't. I did think that it might be due to `close(1)` but commenting that out didn't change the result.
So what I am trying to achieve is something like this:

```
> /bin/ls "/bin/which gcc" /bin/domainname /bin/fake_command
Output:
/usr/bin/gcc
localdomain
Command /bin/which gcc has completed successfully
Command /bin/domainname has completed successfully
a.txt b.c
Command /bin/ls has completed successfully
Command /bin/fake_command has not completed successfully
All done, bye!
>
```

But right now, I'm getting:

```
> /bin/ls "/bin/which gcc" /bin/domainname /bin/fake_command
Output:
Command /bin/which gcc has completed successfully
Command /bin/domainname has completed successfully
Command /bin/ls has completed successfully
Command /bin/fake_command has not completed successfully
>
```

As you can see, my `execv` output for the `/bin/` commands aren't shown in the output.

I've tried searching SO for people who faced this similar issue as me but none of their solutions managed to work for me which is why I'm asking here. If there's anything you're not clear about, please let me know and I will try my best to explain.

**The code:**
q1.c

```
#include "q1.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int
            child_status,
            pipe_array[2];

    pid_t child;

    char *success_or_fail;

    char *msg_buffer = malloc(CHAR_MAX);
    if (msg_buffer == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    struct timespec tw = {.tv_sec = 0, .tv_nsec = 10000000L};

    Tuple *process_tuple;

    size_t tuple_size = sizeof(*process_tuple) + sizeof(pid_t) + sizeof(char *);
    process_tuple = calloc(argc, tuple_size);
    if (process_tuple == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }

//    if (pipe(pipe_array) == -1)
//    {
//        perror("pipe: ");
//        return -1;
//    }

    for (int j = 1; j < argc; j++)
    {
        child = fork();

        if (child == 0)
        {
            int
                    executed,
                    num_of_words,
                    num_of_chars;

            char
                    string[strlen(argv[j]) + 1],
                    *backup = argv[j];

            snprintf(string, sizeof(string), "%s", argv[j]);

            num_of_chars = get_num_of_chars(string);

            num_of_words = get_num_of_words(string);

            char *command[num_of_chars + 1];

            preparing_the_command(num_of_words, string, command);

//            close(pipe_array[0]);
//            close(1);
//            dup2(pipe_array[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
//            write(pipe_array[1], backup, sizeof(backup));

            process_tuple[j - 1].pid = getpid();
            process_tuple[j - 1].command = backup;

            printf(" %i-PID -> %i\n %i-Command -> %s\n\n", process_tuple[j - 1].pid, process_tuple[j - 1].pid, process_tuple[j - 1].pid, process_tuple[j - 1].command);

            executed = execv(command[0], command);

            nanosleep(&tw, 0);

            if (executed == -1)
            {
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            else
            {
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }
        }
        else if (child == -1)
        {
            perror("fork() failed: ");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    printf(" PID -> %i\n Command -> %s\n\n", process_tuple[0].pid, process_tuple[0].command);
//    while ((child = waitpid(-1, &child_status, 0)) != -1)
//    {
//        for (int o = 0; o < argc; o++)
//        {
//            printf(" PID -> %i\n Command -> %s\n\n", process_tuple[o].pid, process_tuple[o].command);
//        }
//        close(0);
//        close(pipe_array[1]);
//
//        dup2(pipe_array[0], STDIN_FILENO);
//        char *recipient;
//
//        read(pipe_array[0], recipient, sizeof(recipient));

//        if (!(WIFEXITED(child_status) && (WEXITSTATUS(child_status) == 0)))
//        {
//            success_or_fail = "not completed successfully";
//        }
//        else
//        {
//            success_or_fail = "completed successfully";
//        }
//        snprintf(msg_buffer, CHAR_MAX, "Command %s has %s\n", recipient, success_or_fail);
//        fputs(msg_buffer, stdout);
//    }
    fputs("All done, bye!\n", stdout);

    free(msg_buffer);

    return 0;
}

int get_num_of_chars(const char string[])
{
    int
            i = 0,
            num_of_chars = 0;

    while (string[i++] != '\0')
    {
        if (string[i] != ' ' && string[i] != '\t')
        {
            num_of_chars++;
        }
    }

    return num_of_chars;
}

int get_num_of_words(const char string[])
{
    int
            i = 0,
            num_of_words = 0;

    bool is_not_separator = false;

    while (string[i++] != '\0')
    {
        if (string[i] == ' ' || string[i] == '\t')
        {
            is_not_separator = false;
        }
        else if (!is_not_separator)
        {
            is_not_separator = true;
            num_of_words++;
        }
    }

    return num_of_words;
}

void preparing_the_command(int num_of_words, char string[], char *command[])
{
    char *token;

    for (int j = 0; j < num_of_words && (token = strtok_r(string, " ", &string)); j++)
    {
        command[j] = token;
    }

    command[num_of_words] = (void *) NULL;
}
```

q1.h

```
#ifndef ASSIGNMENT2Q1_Q1_H
#define ASSIGNMENT2Q1_Q1_H
/***************
 ** LIBRARIES **
 ***************/
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>

/*************
 ** STRUCTS **
 *************/
typedef struct
{
    pid_t pid;
    char *command;
} Tuple;

/*************************
 ** FUNCTION PROTOTYPES **
 *************************/
int get_num_of_chars(const char string[]);

int get_num_of_words(const char string[]);

void preparing_the_command(int num_of_words, char string[], char *command[]);

#endif //ASSIGNMENT2Q1_Q1_H
```

Comment: Why would the child need to tell the parent which command it executed? The parent *knows* which child pid corresponds to which executed command, and `wait()` tells you the child pid. The real problem is of course that you have not read the manpage for `execv()`, so you're fundamentally misunderstanding what it does.

Comment: Another issue: `backup` is not really backuping you `string`. The `preparing_the_command` function uses `strtok_r` on `string`, hence modifying it, and this modification applies to both `argv[j]`, `string` and `backup`, since `string` and `backup` are only *pointers* to a string (to a char array), but they themselves do not contain a copy of the string. To create a copy of the string, you need to create a buffer (e.g. `const char *backup = malloc(1 + strlen(string));` and then copy the contents of `string` to `backup` (using `strcpy` for example).

Comment: Hi @EOF. I know that the parent will know which child pid executed the command but what I need is for the parent to print out the command the child executed and I can't find anywhere online that allows me to get /bin/ps from a child's pid in the parent process, which is why the only way I could think of is for the child process to pass the string "/bin/ps" to the parent. You've mentioned that the problem was that I didn't understand what `execv()` does so I went to read it but I'm not sure what is it that I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: @Orielno Oh right! That's a great catch! Thanks!

Comment: @Ike You want a mapping `pid -> string`. Such a mapping can be created fairly easily, since the image and domain of the mapping are finite. A typical way of storing such a mapping in a modern-ish language would be a hashmap or a tree-map, but since C does not provide such a facility, and implementing one is a fair bit of work,  instead a simple array of `pid, string`-pairs can be stored and searched through. If you keep it sorted by the `pid`, you can binary search so it's not too slow. Also, `man 3 execv`: *RETURN VALUE The exec() functions return only if an error has occurred.*

Comment: @EOF By "a simple array of `pid, string`-pairs", do you mean something like a struct (as seen in the solution here: [How to make a list of pairs in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7944175/10005922)?

Comment: Yes, you can implement the "pair" as a `struct`, and you can then have an array of such structs. You'll need to consider how you represent the "string" part of the pair (for example: you can use a pointer, but then you need to think about whether the pointer owns the pointed-to object (in which case you need to `free()` it at some point), or it points into a common buffer (in which case you must ensure the pointer cannot be dereferenced after the common buffer stops existing (including when it is reallocated))).

Comment: Hi @EOF. I've tried implementing a struct called `Tuple` (my codes have been updated). There isn't any searching done yet, as it's just a test to see whether my parent process can read the struct and unfortunately, it can't. In fact, the values of the struct print out `0` for `pid` and `NULL` for the command members after the `execv`. 
Maybe I might have done it wrong or maybe due to the `execv`, the struct doesn't work. It's the same issue as the pipes, being able to output before the `execv` but not after.

Comment: If you don't understand `fork()`, this is unlikely to be fixable.

Comment: @EOF I went and took a look at the man page for `fork()`. I'm not sure what you might be referring to but would it be this part? 

"The child process is created with a single thread—the one that
          called fork().  The entire virtual address space of the parent
          is replicated in the child, including the states of mutexes,
          condition variables, and other pthreads objects; the use of
          pthread_atfork(3) may be helpful for dealing with problems
          that this can cause."